# Why does Day() return 30 on invalid input?

Tags: vba

This is a problem I discovered, then solved, myself and since I couldn't find a SO question on the topic, I figured I'd create one for future reference.

I accidentally wrote

```
debug.Print day(ow)
```

Instead of

```
debug.Print day(now)
```

To my surprise, rather than throwing an error, I instead got the following result:

```
debug.Print day(ow)
 30
```

Why doesn't it throw an error when given an un-initialised variable as input?

Comment: Maybe this will explain it? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is **default values**.

The following result is illustrative:

```
debug.Print day(0)
 30
```

Why? Because `Day(0)` in the VBA Calendar is the date `30/12/1899`. Demonstrated by the following:

```
debug.Print format(Cdate(0), "dd/mm/yyyy")
30/12/1899
```

---

Unless you write `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, VBA allows you to create variables spontaneously (as `Variant` types) at the first point of use.

When a variable is created (but not set) it is set to its' default value.
Sample Default Values:

> `Long`  --- `0` (Same for other numerics, including `Date`, `Integer`,
>   `Byte`, `Double` etc.)
>   `Boolean` --- `False` (which, in VBA's
>   permissive type system, can be coerced to `0`)
>   `Variant` --- `Empty`
>   (which can also be coerced to `0`)
>   `String` --- `Zero-Length-String ("")` (which, actually, can't be
>   coerced to `0`, and will throw an error if you try to print `Day("")`)
>   `Any Object` --- `Nothing`

So, if you write `Debug.Print Day(Var)` and `Var` is any numeric data type, or a Boolean, or a Variant (or never declared in the first place) then this will be coerced to `Day(0)` which gives the output of `30` as seen above.

---

**In the specific situation in the question:**

VBA recognises `ow` as an undeclared variable, so it creates it (and initialises it to a `Variant` data type) and passes it to `Day()`. Since it is a Variant, it has the initial value `Empty` which is then coerced to `0`, resulting in `Day(0)` which returns `30`.

Comment: This has the potential to be a comprehensive answer (unlike mine which could have been tapped out on an iPhone at a set of traffic lights), especially if you mention `Option Explicit`. Please feel free to take that from my answer.

Comment: Sometimes I forget Stack Overflow's FGITW reality ^^. Will do.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you write `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, VBA allows you to create variables spontaneously (as `Variant` types) at the first point of use.

Such variables are effectively zero-initialised.

So `day(ow)` is equivalent to `day(0)` which evaluates to 30. (Corresponding to 30-Dec-1899).